# building mono small footprint

Tags: mono, makefile, compilation, building, sigabrt

while i build mono-sources with --enable-small-config --enable-minimal=aot,profiler..(all flags)
source-versions: 2.8 , 2.6.4 , 2.6 , 2.4 , 2.0
i get either:

`./.libs/libmonoruntime.a(reflection.o): In function 'mono_reflection_get_token':
reflection.c:(.text+0x160b): undefined reference to 'mono_class_is_reflection_method_or_constructor'`

lots of undefined references
or a

`=================================================================

Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.   =================================================================`

error

anyone know how to handle any of those errors or has succesfully
build a mono small footprint?

Comment: Reflection is not enabled for the small/minimal profile. Read the ECMA docs. Else report the bug to Mono.

Comment: ok but i disabled everything with --enable-minimal= ...,reflection_emit...

Comment: ok when i only go with --enebale-minimal=aot,profiler build seems fine for 2.4.23